# Unable to re-use a variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

I have the two variables in my code. I wish to re-use the first variable after updating the second variable with the data. However, when I clear the first variable, the data in the second variable also gets cleared.

Below is my code: (I have simplified the code to get the issue across)

```
class DataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Users user;
  const DataScreen({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DataScreen> createState() => _DataScreenState();
}

class _DataScreenState extends State<DataScreen> {
List<double> divTemp= []
List<Map<String, Map<String, List<dynamic>>>> divData = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    future = _future();
  }
  
  Future<int> _future() async {
    var step1 = await _getDivData();
    if (step1 == 0) {
        Get.to(() => ChartViewThree(user: widget.user, divdata: divData));
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  Future<int> _getDivData() async {
   for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        divTemp.add(i);
   }       
     divData.addAll([{'D01': {"Deg": divTemp}}]);
     
    divTemp.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        divTemp.add(i+1);
   }       
     divData.addAll([{'D02': {"Deg": divTemp}}]); 
     
  }
}
```

When I use divTemp.clear(), the data in divData is also cleared. I do not wish to create a temp variable for every loop, hence would like to re-use divTemp again.

After this of course I have the build Widget which I am not showing here for keeping the focus on the issue.

Any comments on this is welcome.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz You have a good eye at detecting GetX lol, I did not even notice that

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks for the video share. Very informative on Getx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `divTemp` to other variable, you are passing the reference to the original list, so the value that correspond to the `"Deg"` key inside `divData` still refers to the same list as the one that the `divTemp` variable refers.

There are several ways to copy a list, one way is to use the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators):

```dart
[...divTemp]
```

This will do a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying), but is sufficient for your case since the element type is `double`.

So the line would be:

```dart
divData.addAll([{'D01': {"Deg": [...divTemp]}}]);
```

This way, `[...divTemp]` will create a totally new list, so operations applied to `divTemp` won't affect this new list.

---

See also:

- [Object copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying)